# Event data correlation

Tags: regression, matlab, cross-correlation

I have two sets of data from two different types of sensor. For each instance a sensors output exceeds a threshold the amplitude and time is it is logged as an event.  Thus each event consists of a time and amplitude.

Here is a graph the events of Sensor A and B, you can see visually that there is some correlation between the amplitudes and event timings.
[image]
Here is a graph showing the cumulative number of events of sensor A and B , you can see some correlations with the event frequency here as well.
[image]

How can I show that the events from sensor A are dependant or correlated with sensor B statistically? I use Matlab to process my data; any help or suggestions would be very helpful my knowledge of statistics is a bit limited.

Cheers,
Jim

edit: Here is a scatter version of the amplitude graph as requested:
[image]

Comment: These graphs, which appear to be logging amplitudes continuously over time, do not seem to be consistent with your description, which suggests logging would consist of intermittent values followed by periods of nothing. Could you clarify the connection between the graphs and your description? Note, too, that you don't give adequate information for assessing the relationships among the two sensors. A scatterplot of their values would be helpful. Are the sensors monitoring the same thing or two different things? What exactly are they monitoring?

Comment: The data looks like it is continuous because of the sheer number data points, but I assure you it is event driven; the time between events is not constant.
Sensor A is measuring voltage from a source and sensor B is measuring acoustics vibrations from the same source. My hypothesis is that the acoustic vibrations events cause the voltage events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visually there is much more variability in B thus one might need to account for error variance heterogeneity when constructing a Transfer Function between the two series. Furthermore there may not only be a contemporaneous relationship but a possible lagged relationship between the tho series. Any parametric model should include provisions for unexplained pulses. level shifts. seasonal pulses or locaL time trends. The last time I looked Matlab was seriously wanting in these regards/analytics but perhaps you can cobble together a primitive solution.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Using the data I could construct a transferee function to represent the system; but I don’t know how I would use the TF to show the correlation between A and B. Can you point me in the direction literature on this topic?

Comment: the transfer function is like a regression model BUT it can incorporate lags and an ARIMA component. There is no one statistic that matches the simple correlation coefficient. There is an R-sq which presents the amount of error variance explained by the model. You could ( guess !) take the square root of that value and compare it a simple bi-variate cross-correlation. Please don't tell anybody (just kidding ! ) that I told you to do that.because they will come and take away my three degrees in Statistics and turn me into an accountant or a programmer..

Comment: Thanks IrishStat I have a good idea about how to go about this now.